# React Native & AWS Client STS

Tags: react-native, aws-sdk, aws-secrets-manager, aws-sts, react-native-config

I am trying to get cross account credentials for AWS Client Secret Manager by calling main function in the file.

I am getting an error saying `Error: Credentials Missing`

I tried everything, except for putting the credentials and storing them on my computer. I do not want to do that because I am working with a team and I don't want them to have to go to the files to have to change their AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID & AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY

I have an .env file and react-native-config installed and the keys are there and they are correct, but they seem inaccessible to AWS, therefore I decided to force-put them in process.env object just for testing purposes. Didn't really work.

This is my code, what should I do? I am really lost this is the first time I am connecting AWS to react native project and honestly, AWS docs are not any good. They only provide NodeJS examples, which works a bit differently compared to React Native.

```
import 'react-native-url-polyfill/auto';
import 'react-native-get-random-values';
import {
  SecretsManagerClient,
  GetSecretValueCommand,
} from '@aws-sdk/client-secrets-manager';
import * as sts from '@aws-sdk/client-sts';
import Config from 'react-native-config';

const splitSecretName = 'mobile_split_test';
const secretClient = new SecretsManagerClient({
  region: 'us-east-1',
});
const stsClient = new sts.STS({region: 'us-east-1'});

const main = async () => {
  process.env.AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID = Config.AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID;
  process.env.AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY = Config.AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY;
  await getCrossAccountCredentials();
};

const getCrossAccountCredentials = async () => {
  return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    const timestamp = new Date().getTime();
    const params = {
      RoleArn: 'some arn path here',
      RoleSessionName: `be-descriptibe-here-${timestamp}`,
    };
    console.log(Config);
    stsClient.assumeRole(params, (err, data) => {
      if (err) {
        console.log('getCrossAccountCredentailsError', err);
        reject(err);
      } else {
        resolve({
          accessKeyId: data.Credentials.AccessKeyId,
          secretAccessKey: data.Credentials.SecretAccessKey,
          sessionToken: data.Credentials.SessionToken,
        });
      }
    });
  });
};

export const getSplitSecretKey = async () => {
  const accessParams = await getCrossAccountCredentials();
  //Replace 'YOUR_SECRET_ID' with the ID or ARN of the secret containing your Split.io authorization key.
  let params = {
    SecretId: splitSecretName,
    credentials: accessParams,
    // VersionStage: 'AWSCURRENT', // VersionStage defaults to AWSCURRENT if unspecified
  };

  try {
    const response = await secretClient.send(new GetSecretValueCommand(params));
    console.log('response', response);
    return response.SecretString;
  } catch (error) {
    // For a list of exceptions thrown, see
    // https://docs.aws.amazon.com/secretsmanager/latest/apireference/API_GetSecretValue.html
    console.log('ggetSplitSecretKeError', error);
  }
};
```

Comment: This was my issue and I actually had no permission - I don't remember how I resolved it but it had something to do with the IAM roles in AWS, I didn't have to change the code, but I had to change the permissions.